# Stylus-loader is not compiling files in Webpack 3

Tags: webpack, webpack-2, stylus

I'm trying to get Webpack to compile my stylus files, it's importing them all but it doesn't seem to be compiling anything into CSS.

Here is my Webpack config file:

```
const webpack = require('webpack')
const path = require('path')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin')
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')
const FaviconsWebpackPlugin = require('favicons-webpack-plugin')

const jeet = require('jeet')
const rupture = require('rupture')
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer-stylus')

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: './src/app.js',
    vendor: [
      'lodash'
    ]
  },
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  output: {
    // name will match each entry point above and 'chunkchash' will ensure each new build doesn't cache
    filename: '[name].[chunkhash].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      // Process css styles
      {
        test: /\.styl$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          use: [
            'css-loader', 'stylus-loader'
          ]
        })
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    // Delete old build so we have a fresh start each time
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist']),
    // Process styles
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      options: {
        stylus: {
          use: [
            jeet(),
            rupture(),
            autoprefixer({ browsers: ['> 3%'] })
          ]
        },
        context: '/'
      }
    }),
    // Don't inject the styles as a style tag, extract them into core.css
    new ExtractTextPlugin('core.css'),
    // Generate all our site icons
    // Generate our HTML files for us
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/app.html',
      filename: 'index.html',
      inject: 'body'
    }),
    // Prevent unchanging modules from updating their hash
    new webpack.HashedModuleIdsPlugin(),
    // Put common vendor chunks into their own bundle
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'vendor'
    }),
    // Put common internal chunks into their own bundle
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'common'
    })
  ]
}
```

I've removed a few of the non-style related loaders for the sake of brevity and there are other non-styling related things in webpack.dev.js and webpack.prod.js.

As other people have commented on other posts, the stylus-loader documentation is atrocious and I have looked at so many resources now I can't tell which parts are Webpack 1 and which parts are Webpack 2 or 3.

I am using Webpack v3.6.0 by the way but if my problems can be resolved by switching to 2, I'm happy to do so.

Comment: Deleting node_modules and running npm install again seemed to fix the issue, it must have been a bug/compatibility issue.